# Android Mobile as Gesensor Remote for Google TV

Tags: android, accelerometer, google-tv, gyroscope

I want to use my android phone as remote for my android tv box or google tv. i want play motion games remotely on google tv remotely using accelerometer of my mobile over the wifi communication.

Answer (score 0):

We aren't offering any protocols for this.  You might wish to open a socket on your TV when the app is running, and listen for input, then your remote can send messages to that socket.  While you could use either TCP or UDP, I think you'll find UDP gives better performance.

Comment: google tv is a android device and those application takes input from g-sensor or accelerometer according to their defined format. It is difficult for me to reverse engineer every application.

Comment: Didn't realize you only wanted to develop the remote, not a 2 part app.  Nothing for that, sorry.

Comment: You might be able to enhance the Anymote protocol, or add a complimentary service that enhances the Anymote protocol on the Google TV.   Source is available here: https://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/